# OpenDaylight Archetypes JAR Fluorine Not in Repository?

Tags: opendaylight

I am trying to install OpenDaylight Fluorine. Per the developer guide i am to call mvn generate:archetype alongside some other parameters which can be found here: [link](https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/stable-fluorine/developer-guide/developing-apps-on-the-opendaylight-controller.html)

However, due to the incorrect formatting of the repo's that documention seems to be incorrect.

I've found what i thought to be the correct nexus repo. Here's the link for the nexus repo: [link](https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/org/opendaylight/controller/archetypes/archetypes-parent/0.9.0-SNAPSHOT/)

Here's the command i am trying to run:

```
 mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.opendaylight.controller.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=archetypes-parent -DarchetypeVersion=0.9.0-SNAPSHOT -X
```

My problem is that when i run it i am getting the error:
org.apache.maven.archetype.downloader.DownloadException: Error downloading org.opendaylight.controller.archetypes:archetypes-parent:jar:0.9.0-SNAPSHOT.

Which makes sense because there isn't a jar there in the repo. My question is where could i find this JAR at? Or am i not running the maven command properly? If i go to parent directories none of the previous releases have a JAR either. I can't find any documentation on another way to install this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The archetype artifacts had expired from our repository (which is a side-effect of our unfortunate reliance on snapshot artifacts). We’ve update the archetypes and pushed them to the repository again; they are available [here](https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/opendaylight.snapshot/org/opendaylight/archetypes/opendaylight-startup-archetype/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/) and usable with

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.opendaylight.archetypes \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=opendaylight-startup-archetype \
    -DarchetypeCatalog=remote -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
```